# How to extends class from other js file without declaration file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

### 3th Javascript Lib

```
// publish at npm event-emitter
export default class EventEmitter{
  emit(){
    // do something
  }
  on(){
    // do something
  }
}
```

#### Typescript File

```
import EventEmitter from 'event-emitter';

class Http extends EventEmitter{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.emit(); // error TS2339: Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'Http'
  }
}
```

**error TS2339: Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'Http'**

The question is: How to extends this class if it don't have index.d.ts file?

and I build this with webpack. When I build success. 
I found **import eventEmitter from 'event-emitter';** equal undefined.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `EventEmitter` not `eventEmitter`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to suppress the type check errors you will need to provide a declaration file to TypeScript. If you use popular npm packages the chances are very high that you can find the typings for it on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

You can install [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) typings from their npm @typings private package for TypeScript 2.x or use the [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) package manager for TypeScript 1.x.

Example:

```
// for TypeScript 2.x or you can still use typings
npm install @types/angularjs

// for TypeScript 1.x
npm install -g typings
typings install angularjs --save
```

In case you can't find typings for your package, you can easily write them. Just follow this guide from the TypeScript documentation on [how to write declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).

Afterwards, feel free to publish them! The community will be really thankful.

Cheers!